# Copy autodiscovery results from list to an array

Tags: c#, array

I copy addresses from the endpoints to an array that should only hold the endpoint addresses. This works but it seems so old school :/

Can I make this faster, better, more sexy (LINQ)?

```
public static EndpointAddress[] Find()
{
    EndpointAddress[] endpointAddresses = null;
    var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    var findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(
        new FindCriteria(
            typeof(ICommunicationService)));

    if(findResponse != null) 
    {
        if(findResponse.Endpoints.Count > 0) 
        {
            endpointAddresses = new EndpointAddress[findResponse.Endpoints.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i <= findResponse.Endpoints.Count; i++)
            {
                endpointAddresses[i] = findResponse.Endpoints[i].Address;
            }
        }
    }

    return endpointAddresses ?? new EndpointAddress[0];
}
```

Comment: Does this code even work? `i <= findResponse.Endpoints.Count` should cause an index out of range error.

Comment: It isn't worth an answer of its own, but I don't think you should use `var` for `findResponse` since it is impossible to figure what is the type just by looking at the code!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You certainly can! You're currently coding using the "arrow pattern" it's often nicer to return early rather than keep indenting further and further as you nest conditionals.

```
if (findResponse == null) 
{
     return new EndpointAddress[0];
}
```

Now let's make the rest of the method shorter:

```
public static EndpointAddress[] Find()
{
    var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    var findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(
        new FindCriteria(
            typeof(ICommunicationService)));

    if(findResponse == null) 
    {
        return new EndpointAddress[0];
    }
    return findResponse.Endpoints.Select(endpoint => endpoint.Address).ToArray();
}
```

But, we can go further. You should prefer returning interfaces rather than concrete representations. Do you need indexed access to the EndpointAddresses? I doubt it, return `IEnumerable<EndpointAddress>` instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<EndpointAddress> Find()
{
    var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    var findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(
        new FindCriteria(
            typeof(ICommunicationService)));

    if(findResponse == null) 
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<EndpointAddress>();
    }
    return findResponse.Endpoints.Select(endpoint => endpoint.Address);
}
```

You could also inject the `DiscoveryClient` into the classes constructor but as it is a static method and I don't know what the rest of the class looks like, I'll leave that point for now.

Comment: I like this version! Nice explanation! Thank you :)

Comment: What do you think of "return findResponse == null ? Enumerable.Empty<EndpointAddress>() : findResponse.Endpoints.Select(endpoint => endpoint.Address);" ?

Comment: @SeveSeve A good change. Getting too used to ReSharper telling me to do things like that to spot them myself!

Comment: If you return `IEnumerable<EndpointAddress>`, your query will be lazy evaluated, I don't know avec the return type of `findResponse`, but if it happens to be a lazy evaluated `IEnumerable<>` too, you could have a problem. Simply adding `.ToList()` at the end of the return would evaluate the expression, and you can still return `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: @TopinFrassi - `Endpoints` is a `Collection<T>` which is not lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 7):

If findResponse.EndPoints is an IEnumerable, this one line should work for you:

```
endpointAddresses = findResponse.Endpoints.Select(endpoint => endpoint.Address).ToArray();
```

Comment: Following this line: `findResponse.Endpoints.Count`, you can assume that this is a `List<Endpoint>`. And since a `List<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>`, your line *will* work. :)

Comment: @Abbas, you can't assume that its a `List<T>` just because it has a `Count` property.

Comment: Since it has that property, I assume it is some form of List<T> or similar to that because in .NET, by my knowledge the only collections that have this property. And since. It is the result of some sort of webservice call, I'll assume it is a List<T> or similar.

Comment: It's actually `Collection<T>` but having indexed acess and a count property is a good indication of `ICollection<T>` (and `IEnumerable<T>`) but it's no guarantee.

Comment: @Abbas, Yes a lot of the time it's going to be a collection but I'm trying to get across the point that you can't assume a type base on knowing property. In this case `Endpoints` could quite easily be a custom class which has a `Count` property.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I was referring to this specific case. Nonetheless, your point is 100% valid.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can rewrite the code using linq

```
    public static EndpointAddress[] Find()
    {
        List<EndpointAddress> endpointAddresses = new List<EndpointAddress>();
        var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
        var findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(
            new FindCriteria(
                typeof(ICommunicationService)));

        if (findResponse != null && findResponse.Endpoints.Any())
        {
            endpointAddresses.AddRange(findResponse.Endpoints.Select(metadata => metadata.Address));
        }

        return endpointAddresses.ToArray();
    }
```

In the above code I have used `findResponse.Endpoints.Any` instead of using findResponse.Endpoints.Count. Then linq query is used to fetch the address. I have used a List for endpointAddresses as you have initialize it multiple times if its an array. I am not sure if findResponse is null. If it is never null then you can avoid the null check.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code, code-only answers are not recommended on CodeReview.

Answer (score 2):

While I would probably use LINQ, just because I like it, you don't have to. In order to make the code a bit less clunky, just remove the parts that are not needed.

```
public static EndpointAddress[] Find()
{
    var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    var findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(ICommunicationService)));

    int numberOfEndpoints = findResponse != null ? findResponse.Endpoints.Count : 0;
    var endpointAddresses = new EndpointAddress[numberOfEndpoints];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEndpoints; i++)
    {
        endpointAddresses[i] = findResponse.Endpoints[i].Address;
    }

    return endpointAddresses;
}
```

The check for `null` is really only needed to determine the size of the output array. The check for emptiness isn't needed at all.